# posting checkbox data to views in Django

Tags: python, html, django, post, checkbox

I am absolutely baffled about this.  I am using a checkbox form to get a list of items (tags) to view from the user, so that they can customize the view on their page.

```
data=request.POST
```

data has the value:

```
<QueryDict: {…, u'tags': [u' blue', u'hi', u'sky'], …}>
```

but when I try to retrieve the list of tags:

```
debug=data[‘tags’]
```

debug stores only the value

```
u'sky'
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening, but it's totally screwing me over.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`request.POST` is a [`QueryDict`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) - if you're expecting multiple values for a key, use its `getlist` method.:

```
debug = data.getlist('tags')
```